# Margin merge is not merging as expected

Tags: html, css

Im trying to build a layout for a site  and here is my css and html.

Problem:

1.With header and navigation div, I dont use the margin merge but still feel it got merge
2.With navigation and left-nav/content divs the merge is not happening

Can someone explain whats happening?

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
    </div>
    <div id="left-nav">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
 html, body { 
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%; 

        }

    #container {
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%; 


    }
    #header {
        height: 15%; 
        width: 100%; 
        background-color:grey;
        margin:1%;

    }

    #navigation {
        height: 5%; 
        width: 100%; 
        background-color:grey;
        margin:1%;
    }

    #left-nav {
        height: 40%; 
        width: 20%; 
        background-color:grey;
        margin:1%;
        float:left;
    }

    #content {
        height: 40%; 
        width: 70%; 
        background-color:grey;
        margin:1%;
     float:left;   
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7L98c/)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "margin merge"?

Comment: Both Div's Header and Navigation has margins-1% attached to it..So, when I try to position them together, I will get a 2% margin..but I need a 1% margin between them

Comment: then give 0.5 each ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all you need to do is to use a global CSS reset or

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

which will remove also the default margin the browser adds to `body`.

than just go all over your CSS and **remove** `width: 100%;` from your DIV elements cause they are already set to `auto` by default (being block-level elements).

Now that you've done that, for all other elements, all you need is some simple math...

```
100% - (1%(or 0.5%?) margin * 2sides * No of elements) etc :)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7L98c/2/

Answer (score 0):

The merge doesn't happen between navigation and left-nav/content is that you float left-nav and content. When an element is "float", margin around it would not merge  with others'.